# Ubuntu with Intel Ethernet I217-V does not work

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

My company bought some notebooks and we are installing Ubuntu on them.

But, the ethernet driver is an Intel I217-V. So far, it have been a headache, we are having some troubles to make it work.

I already tried update module to 3.2.4.2 and disable Wake on Lan (from Windows installation).

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Kernel: 3.19.0-25

As you can see, eth0 interface dosn't even appear on ifconfig:

```
user@host:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:4515 (4.5 KB)  TX bytes:4515 (4.5 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:e2:30:bf:ad:95  
      inet addr:192.168.1.145  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42e2:30ff:febf:ad95/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6161838 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:287115 (287.1 KB)

user@host:~$ dmesg |grep e1000e
[    2.218548] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.219292] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.4.2-NAPI
[    2.219294] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    2.219405] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PCI INT A: failed to register GSI
[    2.219411] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -1
[  227.804852] Modules linked in: ctr ccm dm_crypt intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel arc4 aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 rtl8723be lrw gf128mul btcoexist snd_hda_codec_via glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd rtl8723_common snd_hda_codec_generic rtl_pci rtlwifi mac80211 joydev snd_rawmidi serio_raw snd_hda_intel uvcvideo snd_hda_controller videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep videobuf2_memops cfg80211 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev rtsx_pci_ms media lpc_ich memstick btusb snd_pcm shpchp mei_me mei dell_smo8800 tpm_infineon rfcomm snd_seq bnep snd_seq_device snd_timer bluetooth snd ie31200_edac mac_hid edac_core soundcore parport_pc ppdev lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 psmouse ahci libahci rtsx_pci e1000e(OE) i2c_algo_bit ptp drm_kms_helper pps_core drm wmi video

user@host:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
PCI (sysfs)  

*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   version: 05
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c3d000-f7c3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 40:e2:30:bf:ad:95
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.19.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.145 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7b00000-f7b0
```